# Consulta Método rest enviar archivo

Tags: java, json, rest, spring-boot

Tengo un consulta envío un archivo por un método `rest` (**JSON**), tengo la duda si usar `Base64` o `byte[]`, quisiera saber que es lo mas optimo y porque?

En un comienzo el archivo no debería tener mas de **20MG**.

cabe señalar que esta funcionando de ambas maneras solo quiero saber que es mejor.

Saludos.

Comment: Define `mejor`: ¿ Menos *byes* ? ¿ Menos consumo de CPU al enviarlo ? ¿ Menos consumo de CPU al recibirlo ? Lo que no le pese al cliente, le pesará al servidor, y viceversa.

Comment: diría mas bien en cuanto a la transferencia del archivo en si, que no llegue corrupto, velocidad facilidad de leer el archivo.

Comment: Base64 Hace que pese 4/3 lo que el original